# Remote Desktop Settings doesnt see imported Certificate

Tags: .net, azure, x509certificate, remote-desktop, rdp

I have imported my certificate in

> [Certificates - Current User\Personal\Certificates]

This is also where Visual Studio creates its new certificates for RDP when requested.

When I then go over my Cloud project , right click and select

> "Configure Remote Desktop Settings" --> Enable connections for all roles

I can't see my certificate in the dropdown. I don't understand why.

I have even selected the WebRole itself, went under properties and --> Certificates and selected the Thumbprint of my certificate successfully.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upload that certificate you created to your deployment with the Azure Management Portal.

So if you go to your hosted services then click the certificates folder you can then upload your newly created certificate there.

**Final answer:**
Create a certificate then use the certificate snapin for both Current User and Local Computer in Management Console (mmc) to drag the cert from Local Computer/Personal to Current User/Personal

Comment: Yes thats clear. I am talking about within Visual Studio while packaging and wanting to setup RDP.

Comment: I see. It looks as though you have done everything correctly. I usually create a certificate then use the certificate snapin for both Current User and Local Computer in Management Console (mmc) to drag the cert from Local Computer/Personal to Current User/Personal. But it looks as though you have done that, right?

Comment: Cool. I'll just stick my comment in the answer for other people

Comment: This isn't solving it for me; I have my certificate in both Local Computer/Personal and Current User/Personal, but it still doesn't show up in the "Configure Remote Desktop" dialog. I see only "<Automatic>" and "<Create>". Is there some property that the certificate has to have that I could be missing?